# Why does this function work but still returns the typeError ... is not a function?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am learning js and am confused on one thing.  I am just copying/pasting the code example from mdn...

```
  function Person(gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

Person.prototype.sayGender = function() {
    alert(this.gender);
};

var person1 = new Person('Male');
var genderTeller = person1.sayGender;

person1.sayGender(); // alerts 'Male'
genderTeller(); // alerts undefined
alert(genderTeller === person1.sayGender); // alerts true
alert(genderTeller === Person.prototype.sayGender); // alerts true
```

in the example above `genderTeller` will return `undefined` but after slightly modifying it in the second example:

```
function Person(gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

Person.prototype.sayGender = function() {
        alert(this.gender);
    };

var person1 = new Person('Male');
var genderTeller = person1.sayGender();
genderTeller();
```

the genderTeller function actually works but also returns 'typeError: genderTeller is not a function.'

Why is genderTeller not a function in the second example when it's clearly assigned to a method?

Comment: A couple of valuable resources for you:  Crockford (http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html) and JS Garden (http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/).

Comment: yuppers. I did a JS binge last week (probably the same thing you're doing right now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you are assigning a function to a variable and executing it.  The `this` in that case is window, since you are just calling the function and not calling it *on* anything.

In the second case, you are invoking the function and assigning its result to `genderTeller`.  Since the function doesn't return anything, the variable is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
var genderTeller = person1.sayGender();
```

You are assigning the *value returned by calling* the function since you are executing it, not the function itself.

Since the function doesn't actually return a value, it's not a function (or anything at all, really), which is why you are getting that error.

Comment: Further exploring, I realized how it wouldn't return a type error.  though there's probably an infinite number of ways to do this better.

Comment: function Person(gender) {      this.gender = gender; }
    Person.prototype.sayGender = function(){
      alert(this.gender); };  var person1 = new Person('Male');
    function genderTeller() {person1.sayGender()}; genderTeller();           //undefined